# Ubee EVW3226 drops connections to its external, public IP, address from clients behind NAT

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I have a Ubee EVW3226 router/modem from UPC ISP. I host some services and have a few ports redirected. I cannot access my hosted service, using my domain name or external IP address. The router drops connections to its external, public, IP address from clients behind NAT. For external clients it works fine. How to allow internal clients, to access resources available on forwarded ports of the router.

Sample use case is a mobile phone with an IP cam access. It is best to use one address (domain name) for usage from external network (cellular data) or from internal WiFi network. Now, it works for me external network, but not from internal.

I want to use this router in "router mode", not "bridge mode". I'm looking for a solution, not involving another router. I want to correct the behavior of the Ubee EVW3226.

I've already tried to disable router's firewall. This doesn't change anything in this matter.

Does anyone know if this router have some console? How to access it?

Comment: Use IPs internally, instead of domain names.

Comment: I know that and already used this workaround, but that's not a solution. When an IP cam app is used on a smartphone it needs two different sources to be configured. One with external address (domain name) and the other with internal IP address.

Comment: I'm going to workaround it using a separate DNS server which will resolve my domain name to an internal IP address, but still this workaround requires a second device.

Answer (score 1):

You need a feature in the router/modem called  **NAT hairpinning**.

If your device can't support it then a machine on the LAN will be unable to access another machine on the LAN via the external IP address .